# Problem concatenating json_ecode'd data

Tags: php, json

In a while loop I set up this array:

```
$prejsonarray[] = json_encode(array( 'dealerName'=> $row_1, 'dealerAddress' => $addressstring  ));
```

Then outside it I try to concatenate the JSON data into a single string:

```
foreach($prejsonarray as $v){ $dealersstring .= "$v " }
```

And I get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

For the `foreach` line. However, if I echo out `$prejsonarray[0]` I can see it contains the expected JSON data.

Any ideas?

Comment: YOu are missing a semicolon after ` $dealersstring .= "$v " `

Comment: $dealersstring .= "$v " should be  $dealersstring .= $v+" " beside ; as @Pekka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach($prejsonarray as $v){ $dealersstring .= "$v "; }`

Missing the ;

Answer (score 1):

You should not just concatenate JSON strings. The result is most likely *not* a valid JSON string, if this is what you want as result. In this case, encode the whole array:

```
$prejsonarray[] = array('dealerName'=> $row_1, 'dealerAddress' => $addressstring );
```

At the end:

```
$dealersstring = json_encode($prejsonarray);
```

---

However, you get the syntax error because you are missing a semicolon `;`:

```
foreach($prejsonarray as $v){ $dealersstring .= "$v "; }
//                                                   ^
```

Instead of the concatenating array values this way, you should use [`implode` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$dealersstring = implode(' ', $prejsonarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($prejsonarray as $v){ $dealersstring .= "$v "; }
```

you just have to add a semi colon.

the reason why the parser throws an error "unexpected }" because after the end of a line there needs to be a statement terminator which is none other than ";" so when it looks for a semicolon but in your case it has a " } "